# How to click on second element from list of web element in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'statsprogramsgridmodal')]//div[contains(@class,'ui-grid-icon-ok')]")
```

I have written above xpath to find the web element. It gives me three result. I want to click on second web element. Could you please tell me how it can be done in python selenium?

Comment: Which second element? Sibling? Can you give us an html example please.

Comment: That is not sibling, all three are at same lavel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with an xpath returning the 2nd match from all results :

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
  "(//div[contains(@class,'statsprogramsgridmodal')]//div[contains(@class,'ui-grid-icon-ok')])[2]")
```

with an xpath returning the 2nd child from the same level :

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
  "//div[contains(@class,'statsprogramsgridmodal')]//div[contains(@class,'ui-grid-icon-ok')][2]")
```

or with an xpath returning multiple elements:

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
  "//div[contains(@class,'statsprogramsgridmodal')]//div[contains(@class,'ui-grid-icon-ok')]")[1]
```

or with a css selector returning multiple elements:

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
  "div[class*='statsprogramsgridmodal'] div[class*='ui-grid-icon-ok']")[1]
```

Comment: Your first solution did work for me. Only problem is index numbering. For my case if I set [2] index after xpath, it selects the 3rd element and [1] select the second element and [0] index select the first one. You just change it, I will accept your answer

Comment: @Shoaib Akhtar, an XPath takes a base 1 index and the command returns a base 0 array. Could you check it again. Be aware that `(//xxx/xxx)[2]` returns the second result while `//xxx/xxx[2]` returns the 2nd child.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not putting the xpath in braces driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//xxx/xxx)[2]"). Your solution is working well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yourXpath/following-sibling::node()').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yourXpath/following-sibling::theTag').click()
```

Where the theTag is whatever you want: div, tr, ul, ...